# How to remove index.php and index from the URL using htaccess | PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on a PHP website for QA forum. My website contains a qa folder like -

example.com/qa/
In the qa folder, I have an index.php file. I am getting QA post from datatabase like -

example/qa/index/506/how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php

I am using htaccess code (htaccess located in the same qa folder ) -

```
RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^index/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [NC,L]
```

According to this htaccess file, I can open URL like -

```
example/qa/index/506/how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php
```

not

```
example.com/qa/index.php?id=506&slug=how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php
```

This is working well and I like it but the main thing starts from here.
I want to remove index from url

before

```
example/qa/index/506/how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php
```

after

```
example/qa/506/how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php
```

I have used this code in the same htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]

RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

but it's not working.
One more thing, I will create more pages in qa folder like - login.php, register.php.

How can I remove the index from the URL without effects on other pages in qa folder.

Comment: Remove the `index/` part from your RewriteRule?!

Comment: @VishalRana, could you please post front end url, which you want to being served from backend url for clarification of question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Now, it's working well. I have removed index/ from RewriteRule according to brombeer. Thanks again for your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to remove the index from url

```
example.com/qa/index.php?id=506&slug=how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php
```

to

```
example/qa/index/506/how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php
```

before

Just create a htaccess file in your folder where is index.php located.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [NC,L]
```

after

```
example/qa/506/how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php
```

It will be more valuable for future visitors.
If you want to remove PHP (.php ) extension from any page inside the folder

before

```
example.com/qa/login.php
```

after
Add code line on htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^login\/?$ login.php
```

Now, you can open URL like -

```
example.com/qa/login
```

It's another htaccess method to remove PHP extension .php from the Page URL using htaccess file .